# How to random name FILES and keep old TYPE_FILE in loop

Tags: php

for example i want to upload file name moble.jpg  and i want to store it like XXDSSDFS.jpg i try to use pathinfo but when i print_r it return nothing, I think i should return like jpg or png . 
NOTE assume that i upload 2 img

```
$text           =   $_POST['spec_text'];
$file_spec          =   $_FILES['spec_file']['name'];
$typefile       =   $_FILES['spec_file']['type'];   
$sizefile       =   $_FILES['spec_file']['size'];
$filename = md5($_FILES['spec_file']['tmp_name']);




$a = count($file_spec);
for ($i=0; $i < count($file_spec); $i++) { 
    if ($typefile[$i] == 'image/png' OR $typefile[$i] == 'image/jpeg')
    {
        echo "string".$filename;
    }else{
        echo "eror";
    }
}
```

Comment: remove un-necessary `for`  loop also confirm that vairables are connect.  `$_FILES['spec_file']` != `$_FILES['product1']`

Comment: `$filename = md5($_FILES['tmp_name'']);` Can you try this code? The name is md5 hashed, but you can also give it your own name. Make sure you do it in a foreach if you have more files.

Comment: `$_FILES['tmp_name'']`!!!!??? @RonnieOosting is it correct?

Comment: @B.Desai I edited my comment. As far as I know, $_FILES['spec_file']['tmp_name'] or $FILES['spec_file']['name'] would do it. In user8663822 his situation it would probably be $_FILES['spec_file']['tmp_name']

Comment: @B.Desai in my html i store 2 img that's why i use loop

Comment: Can you var_dump $_FILES['spec_file'] and see if it's not empty?

Comment: For example: 
if(isset($_FILES['screenshot3']['size']) && $_FILES['screenshot3']['size'] > 0)
{ 
// code 
}

This code checks wether the filename 'screenshot3' size is set and is higher than 0.

Comment: @RonnieOosting `$_FILES` takes first index as field name `name` and `tmp_name` is second index so your suggestion leads to error

Comment: @B.Desai Yea, i figured out. Thats why I posted an example.

Comment: @RonnieOosting i var_dump  spec_file it give me a data but when i var_dump($filename); it print NULL

Comment: var_dump should be on an array, echo on string. The $filename should be a string. So if you var_dump spec_file, and echo $filename you should have result.

Comment: @RonnieOosting its not compulsory that `var_dump` work on array only. for string its also give string value as output. Dont suggest wrong guess

Comment: i update my code it echo nothing  assume that i upload 2 image

Comment: @user8663822 `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: @B.Desai true, thats why i said should. It's just what you prefer to use. Think I am not needed here anymore, since B. Desai is into it.